Is it possible to apply the matrix inverse $(H(\textrm{Id}+F^T F)^{-1}H^T)^{-1}$ to a vector without explicitly calculating the inverse?
This is a continuation of this problem: Minimizing $\frac{1}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2 +\frac{1}{2}\|y-y_0\|^2$ subject to $F(x)=y, G(y)=b$
In this problem, to find the solution to the optimization problem, I need to apply the matrix  $(H(\textrm{Id}+F^T F)^{-1}H^T)^{-1}$ to some vector, where $H, F$ are some matrices(not necessarily square) and $\textrm{Id}$ is an identity.
In general, for an invertible square matrix $A$ and a vector $y$, to calculate $A^{-1}y$, it is the best practice to solve $Ax=y$ instead of calculating $A^{-1}$ and applying to $y$, as explained in Seven Sins of Numerical Linear Algebra.
However, I am not sure if we can do something similar to calculate $(H(\textrm{Id}+F^T F)^{-1}H^T)^{-1}y$ for some vector $y$. Of course, we can solve $H(\textrm{Id}+F^T F)^{-1}H^Tx = y$, but I still need to calculate $(\textrm{Id}+F^T F)^{-1}$ beforehand.
Is there any numerically stable way to conduct this calculation?

Yes. You wish to compute $$x = (H(I + F^TF)^{-1}H^T)^{-1}y$$ for any $y$. You do this by solving the linear system
$$\begin{bmatrix} I + F^TF   & H^T \\ H  & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -y \end{bmatrix}$$
and retrieving $x = x_2$.
Why is this enough? The matrix $I+F^TF$ is symmetric positive definite. It follows that
$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc|c} I + F^T F & H^T & 0 \\ H &  0 & -y\end{array} \right] \sim \left[\begin{array}{cc|c} I + F^T F & H^T & 0 \\ 0 & - H(I+F^TF)^{-1} H^T & -y \end{array} \right] \sim \left[\begin{array}{cc|c} I + F^T F & H^T & 0 \\ 0 & I &  (H(I+F^TF)^{-1} H^T)^{-1}y \end{array} \right] $$
The larger system that we solve here is a example of a saddle-point system.
